# Upgrading JasperReports 1.3.1 to JasperReports 4.6

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, report

I am upgrading my *JasperReports* version as mentioned in the title.
I don't know much about the *JasperReports* version upgrade. Which all things I have to change to make it work. I have latest *.jar* files of everything. But when I print my *.PDF* report it gives me this error.

```
error:could not open file because its damaged or not supported.
```

In eclipse it shows this exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PRINTSCALING at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExpor‌​ter.java:532) at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java‌​:396) at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdf(JasperExportManager.‌​java:212) at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(JasperExportMa‌​nager.java:536) at 
com.sibisoft.northstar.util.JasperReportGenerator.getPdfByteArray(JasperReportGe‌​nerator.java:679)
```

Please help me.

Comment: If possible add some screen shots/links.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PRINTSCALING
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:532)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:396)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdf(JasperExportManager.java:212)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(JasperExportManager.java:536)
 at com.sibisoft.northstar.util.JasperReportGenerator.getPdfByteArray(JasperReportGenerator.java:679)

Comment: My guess is that its because there is no method as PrintScaling in v4.6. You better Check the documentation.

Comment: I got that but where I am using this method. can you tell me that.

Comment: Need to look at your code/jrxml.! cant tell you directly. :)

Comment: there is no such method in my jrxml. and i have mad entirely new jasper report with iReport 4.6 it should not come in that report. i think this not the case. that you are pointing

Comment: @FarjadBabar You should post Java code and jrxml file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not with JasperReports but with the version of the iText library you are using. You need to download version 2.1.7 to work with that version of JasperReports. You can get it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7).

---

I happened to know this one off the top of my head, as I ran into it in the past, but as a helpful note in the future, this is the process I used to figure it out originally.

Since JasperReports is open source, the code can be found online easily. So I google:

> site:grepcode.com
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream

To find the code online. (GrepCode basically provides a cool site to look through many open source projects source code.)

At the top of the GrepCode page they have the version of the project, so make sure it is pointing to which ever version you are using.

Then find the method or line number in the error message.

From here it is just like debugging local code. You can see what the offending class is, and what package it belongs to. In this case it points to the itext libray as the culprit.

Hope that helps you out in the future, and happy reporting.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am trying this thing right now. i will let you I will succeed. thanks really for your help

Comment: thanks man i have tried your way of debugging the problem. I actually imported jar source file. it helped me a lot. since i am able to know the exact reason why it was giving this error.

Comment: yes i got this working. problem was exactly that you mentioned.i already was using your mentioned version of itext.  my particular problem was multiple jar files i upgraded one jar file but other jar files was of previous version. that was creating problem.i think when you are working with jar files you should use source jar file as well that will help you a lot. it was my first time. i didn't know this. i got the idea from your post. thanks a lot once again

Comment: hi i am new to the jasper report and i am facing the same issue can u please let me know how to include the suggested jar file ??